# Responsive navi overlaps h1 and navi links on h1 isn't working

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, jquery-mobile-navbar

this is my first message! I can't find answer on my question on the webpage. 
I'm going to do responsive website but I have a problem with mobile navigation on the phone. The navi links overlaps h1 and links dont's react (does not work as it should). The z-index not helps here and the backgorund-color on mobile-navi looks bad and links still don't react.
Give me an answer if you have some idea to fix it.
My webpage: 
http://jakub-lawniczak.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `z-index` to `.main-nav` This will fix your overlaping issue

```
.main-nav {
  position:relative;
  z-index:9;
 }
```

Comment: Thanks very much, now it's react! But it's still overlap h1 and looks bad. What can I make to h1 going down a little when I open mobile-nav?

Comment: you can  set `padding-top` to h1 , just comment here if you need any help